# jQuery min (smallest value) for each individual ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, each, min

I have more than 2 travels on one page with prices, and every travel (div container) should have a start price (the smallest value).

So I wrote this, and it's working...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var vals = $('.prices').map(function () {
    return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) ? parseInt($(this).text(), 10) :  null;
    }).get();

// then find their minimum
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);

// tag any cell matching the min value
    $('.prices').filter(function () {
    return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) === min;
    });

   $('.start-price').text(min);
});
```

but obviously the script is taking the smallest value from all prices on the page (all containers). It should take the smallest value from each (every) travel. The ID's of the containers can be generated dynamic.
How could I achived this?

Comment: Please provide an HTML example.

Comment: If you have a container for each destination (with different offers listed) you could iterate those containers, (say, class='destination'), and then iterate all prices within each container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure each travel div has a class (lets say .travel) and perform the calculation for each.

```
jQuery(function($) {      
    $(".travel").each(function() {

      var $prices = $(this).find(".prices");
      var vals = $prices.map(function () {
        return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) ? parseInt($(this).text(), 10) :  null;
      }).get();

      // then find their minimum
      var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);

      // tag any cell matching the min value
      $prices.filter(function () {
        return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) === min;
      });
      $(this).find('.start-price').text(min);
    });       
});
```